# change the size of nativescript-mapbox custom markers

Tags: angular, nativescript, mapbox

is there a way I can change the size of the custom markers?
I am using this code to change the icon of markers:
iconPath: "assets/bus_top_view.png"

the package I used is:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-mapbox